# Wondering about qooxdoo syntax/parsing

Tags: qooxdoo

I found two lines in my code.

```
test = new qx.ui.form.RadioGroup;
```

I am wondering, if the missing **()** might cause issues or should maybe raise a warning in the generator or the lint job.

```
qx.ui.form.RadioGroup;
```

I think it might be worth reporting it as a "statement without effect" in lint.

Comment: It's a valid js syntax so there's no reason to raise a warning. I think that the parser can handle it but if you are not sure just test it. Anyway that tool is used to compile a minified version of your script but it will be executed by the browser js engine so there shouldn't be any problem

Answer (score 1):

mck89's comment is the answer (I wonder why so many people put valid answers in comments...):

You don't need the parens, and `new qx.ui.form.RadioGroup` is a syntactically correct expression, equivalent to adding a pair of empty parens. (There are some checkers that will warn about this, like I believe JsLint, but qooxdoo doesn't ... :).

In your particular case, the code will also run successfully in the browser, as RadioGroup permits empty constructor args; you can use `.add()` later to add items to the group.

Comment: Thanks to both for the explanation. What about the second case?

Comment: @Quotenjugendlicher Second case?

Comment: The second example. Just the class name in the code, that does nothing at all.

Comment: Mh, yes, it is just a value. But again it's perfectly legal JS, just like `3;`. You could argue about flagging this, but I'm personally not a friend of warnings that are too low-level. You might know the saying about fool-proof systems...